# How to set an Interval in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Recently I tried to make an interval in flutter but I didn't see anything like `setInterval(function(){}, 1000)` in JavaScript. Does it exist in Flutter?

Comment: Is this what you want https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html

Comment: No need to duplicate the question title in the question.

Comment: The above link doesn't works (404 error). New link:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html

Answer (score 116, accepted):

you can use Timer for that.

```dart
Timer timer = new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
   debugPrint("Print after 5 seconds");
});
```

**EDITED**

as pointed by [@MoeinPorkamel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5555258/moeinporkamel) in comments. Above answer is more like `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`! Those who need interval, you can use:

```dart
// runs every 1 second
Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
   debugPrint(timer.tick.toString());
});
```

To use `Timer` you need to `import 'dart:async';`

Comment: also keep in mind to use the timer you need to import async:
`import 'dart:async';`

Comment: this is more like setTimeout instead of interval! Those who need interval, you can use `Timer.periodic`

Comment: @MoeinPorkamel, thanks for pointing out the correct answer. Why don't you form your comment into separate answer, so that it could be upvoted (and accepted) as correct answer instead of this one?

Comment: how can i use this to change the state of a ui in flutter periodically?

Comment: How do we stop it?

Comment: @KevinRED just call setState in function

Comment: @tinyCoder   Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    timer.cancel();
  });

Comment: @AjayKumar both solutions are working, thanks to share. Kindly tell me how can we call a function in Timer.periodic function. I wrote Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
    // debugPrint("Print after 2 seconds");
    increaseCount();
  });  But increaseCount function is not being called every 2 seconds. Kindly share your suggestion. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Kamlesh It looks right so maybe the function increaseCount is getting called but you are missing something else like setState e.t.c.